# Running into a clearfix type issue

Tags: html, css

### So Two Divs Walk Into A Form

Looks like this:

```
<form>
    <div id="top">
        <label>Gimme a Number:<input type="number" /></label><br />
        <label>Gimme a Word:<input type="textarea" /></label><br />
        <label>Now tell me how you feel about HTML forms: <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></label><br />
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <label>Gimme a Number:<input type="number" /></label><br />
        <label>Gimme a Word:<input type="textarea" /></label><br />
        <label>Now tell me how you feel about HTML forms: <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></label><br />
    </div>
</form>
```

There's some css positioning all the form fields `absolute` and `left`, a fiddle of the principal is [here (Step 1)](http://jsfiddle.net/knq2B/)

So I fixed the first problem by adding additional line breaks [(fiddle of step 2)](http://jsfiddle.net/knq2B/1/).

This is not an ideal solution for two reasons. Extra elements in the DOM for one, and um... well just look at it. The `textarea` still overflows into the bottom `div`.

I found a temporary hack when the miscellaneous clearfix answers I tried didn't work (Mostly from other SO questions) by inserting:

```
<hr class="clearfix" /><br />
```

in between the two, and giving the `hr` `visibility:hidden` in the CSS.

That made it work on my page, but as you can see [here (Step 3)](http://jsfiddle.net/knq2B/2/) it doesn't actually work. In the form on my page the `div`'s have transparent backgrounds, and it puts them far enough apart that the users are happy, and since this is an intranet order form (used from a phone no less) and not a SV startup webapp, I'm kind of content to leave it production for now, but in the end, what was the right way to do this?

How should I have gotten the `div.top` to encompass the full content, including the `textarea`? I've tried a lot of the "go to" solutions for elements with `float`, but as expected, they don't work since the `textarea`'s aren't `float`ed.

Ideally I want to ditch the extra `<br>`s, and have the `<div>`s actually contain their content without either manually positioning every single element or adding a ton of complexity to the page. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Does textareas need to be positioned absolutely or it was just one of the approaches? My point is, do you need them to be that way for some other specific purpose or we can try to propose an answer without `position: absolute`?

Comment: doesn't have to be `absolute`, but needs to keep all input/textarea elements in a straight line across from their labels. It's for a construction company, and their very anal retentive about things being straight edges.

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick for what you're looking for is using a [Html Description List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).

For example, you can write this:

```
<dl id="top">
    <dt>Gimme a Number:</dt>
    <dd><input type="number" /></dd>
    <dt>Gimme a Word:</dt>
    <dd><input type="textarea" /></dd>
    <dt>Now tell me how you feel about HTML forms:</dt>
    <dd><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></dd>
</dl>
<dl id="bottom">
    <dt>Gimme a Number:</dt>
    <dd><input type="number" /></dd>
    <dt>Gimme a Word:</dt>
    <dd><input type="textarea" /></dd>
    <dt>Now tell me how you feel about HTML forms:</dt>
    <dd><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></dd>
</dl>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkRPe/)

And here is a bit more css to make it look like your fiddle:

```
#top{
    color:white;
    font-weight:700;
    background-color:blue;
}
#bottom{
    font-weight:700;
    background-color:red;
}

dl {
    padding: 0.5em;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

dd {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkRPe/1/)

**Edit**

About label issue being non-superfluous - there is an easy solution using the "for" attribute. Here is an example:

```
<dt><label for="number1">Gimme a Number:</label></dt>
<dd><input id="number1" type="number" /></dd>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkRPe/2/)

Your original use of label:

```
<label>Gimme a Number:<input type="number" /></label><br />
```

will couple the two tags together and shouldn't be used. Plus talking about semantics, should the input really be part of the label?

Taking in acount your comment about non-semantic use of dd / dt, you can easily swap between the dt and dd, [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkRPe/3/). Here is the updated example:

```
<dd><label for="number1">Gimme a Number:</label></dd>
<dt><input id="number1" type="number" /></dt>
```

Now we have a semantic HTML where the CSS takes care of the design choices.

**Edit 2**

[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkRPe/5/) - no need in `height: 100%;` on dl

Comment: that's a non-semantic use for `dd`/`dt`, in that the description should be in the `dd` and the form element should be in the `dt`, and it still doesn't have a fixed left alignment for the form elements. Also, the `label` tag is non-superfluous, as it allows users to click either the form element or the label to enter input which is a big deal for sausage-fingered mobile users like myself. :)

Comment: Too much to write down in a comment, I added an **Edit** section to my original answer :)

Comment: still need those text areas to be on the right, not underneath. As far as nesting, it represents the desired outcome semantically, (i.e. click anywhere in here to hit the input), but I have no problem with using the `for` attribute either.

Comment: my principal issue is that the `dl` adds (almost) as much markup as a `table` without achieving the required positioning.

Comment: Jason about the textarea - they are underneath only because jsfiddle uses a small frame, try copying the latest fiddle I posted in **Edit 2** to another html and tell me if what you get is satisfying.

Comment: About the table - I disagree, tables are very hard to customize because they should be used for actual tables. Let's say if you want one row to be bigger than the other, in the dl solution it's easy with css only, not like tables requiring you to define the number of columns it should take (Inside the HTML, because it's a structure thing not design).

Comment: clsoer, but I need the left edge of all the right side elements to align. That was specific to the design guide, and believe me not my choice. :)